# EF 6: Dynamically copy a an entry of a DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**Initial situation:**

Select several entries for copying:

```
var violations = entities.StagingViolation.Where(entry => entry.ViolationCode == processingEngineViolation.ViolationCode).ToList();
```

Use reflection to iterator through the properties of "StagingViolation" object and copy all properties. Only the property "ProcessingId" (type: Guid) should be assigned a new value:

```
entities.StagingViolation.AddRange(violations.Select(violation => {
       var newViolation = new StagingViolation();

       typeof(StagingViolation).GetProperties()
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(property => { 
                    typeof(StagingViolation).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(newViolation, property.GetValue(violation, null));
              });

         newViolation.ProcessingId = newProcessingId;

         return newViolation;
}));

entities.SaveChanges();
```

Assuming **StagingViolation** class looks like this:

```
public class StagingViolation {
    public Guid ProcessingId { get; set; }
    public string ViolationCode { get; set; }
    public string ViolationDetailCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Expected result:**

Original **StagingViolation** objects looks like this:

```
ProcessingId = 'B4E3D49F-B8E3-4988-AAF2-42259059FA03'
ViolationCode = 'ABC'
ViolationDetailCode = 'ABC.123'
```

Copied **StagingViolation** should look like this:

```
var newProcessingId = 'F8028E92-7234-4590-8EAB-170DE5B5E6DA'

--------------------

ProcessingId = newProcessingId 
ViolationCode = 'ABC'
ViolationDetailCode = 'ABC.123'
```

But the copied object does contain the same "ProcessingId" as the original object in the end. Somebody knows why?

**EDIT 1:**

This whole functionality is contained in following context:

```
private void CopyViolations(OverrideCodeInput violationOverrideCode, Guid newProcessingId) {
 ...
}
```

I debugged through the iteration and found out that "newProcessingId" contains the correct value and `newViolation.ProcessingId = newProcessingId` was also executed correctly. But in the end, when I use a breakpoint at `entities.SaveChanges` the collection indeed added the new entries, but they contain the old "ProcessingId".

FYI: "ProcessingId" is part of the primary key. That's why I get an exception at `SaveChanges()` to a primary key violation.

Comment: Is `ProcessingId` defined as the key? When exactly do you see the old value, is it only after `SaveChanges()` or even immediately when you set it? Also, where and how is `newProcessingId` initialized?

Comment: @haim770 I edited my post.

Comment: How is the primary key generated? Can you set its value manually at all, or is it database-generated?

Comment: Is `ProcessingId` FK as well? If yes, is there associated navigation property in `StagingViolation` class?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes it is. It is used several times as FK in Navigation Properties

Comment: @haim770 Yes it can be set manually.

Comment: Then I guess its taking the `Id` from the navigation property. So in addition to setting `ProcessingId = newProcessingId` try clearing the navigation property, something like `Processing = null`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thx for your hint. It solved my problem to somehow exclude the `Navigation` properties from being set on the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the help of IvanStoev and haim770 I solved my problem by excluding the **NavigationProperties** from being copied to the new object. Therefore I use an extension for checking the **PropertyType** before iterating over the properties of **StagingViolation**: `property.PropertyType.IsSimpleType()`

```
entities.StagingViolation.AddRange(violations.Select(violation => {
        var newViolation = new StagingViolation();

        typeof(StagingViolation).GetProperties().Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsSimpleType())
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(property => {
                        typeof(StagingViolation).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(newViolation, property.GetValue(violation, null));
    });

    newViolation.ProcessingId = newProcessingId;

    return newViolation;
}));


public static class TypeExtension {
    public static bool IsSimpleType(this Type type) {
        while (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
            type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }

        return type.IsValueType || type.IsPrimitive || new[] { typeof(string), typeof(decimal), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimeOffset), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(Guid) }.Contains(type) || Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object;          
    }
}
```